# How to override global Monolog configuration from a bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, overriding, monolog

I would like to override the global `config.yml` Monolog configuration from inside of my bundle. Hovewer, when I try to write something like:

```
monolog:
    # some new configuration params
```

I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "monolog"
```

Is there a way to modify the configuration without resorting to adding compiler passes?

Comment: Could you paste `AppKernel.php` file?

Comment: You'll need a CompilerPass. What are you trying to configure?

Comment: What's the reason that you want to do that? There might be other ways to achieve what you need

Comment: try to use `prependExtension`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know maybe I'm late, but I have found a solution for this because I wanted to do the same.

In you bundle extension load method, you should register the MonologExtension, then you can load monolog configuration in your bundle config files:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    // Register extension to load monolog configuration in bundle.
    $container->registerExtension(new MonologExtension());

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('config_' . $container->getParameter('kernel.environment') . '.yml');
}
```